# How to write multiple different xml namespace in one element in PHP

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, domdocument, xml-namespaces

I want to build this xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:sec="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1"
xmlns:link="http://wsdl.amadeus.com/2010/06/ws/Link_v1"
xmlns:ses="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3" 
xmlns:ns="http://www.iata.org/IATA/2015/00/2018.1/AirShoppingRQ">
```

here is my php code

```
    public function build() {
        $document = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
        $root = $document->createElementNS(
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
            "soapenv:Envelope"
        );
        $root->setAttributeNS(
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
            "xmlns",
            "sec"
        );

        $document->appendChild($root);

        return $document;
    }
```

my function returns this xml

```
  xml: """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soapenv:xmlns="sec"/>
    """
```

I want soapenv element to have 4 different xmlns. but setting attributes is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlns` references a reserved namespace in XML. So you can explicitly add the definitions as attributes with this namespace:

```
// a dictionary for the namespace URIs - to keep the source readable
$xmlns = [
  //  the reserved xmlns namespace     
  'xmlns' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',
  // soap
  'soap' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
  // others
  'security' => 'http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1',
  'link' => 'http://wsdl.amadeus.com/2010/06/ws/Link_v1',
  'session' => 'http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3',
  'air' => 'http://www.iata.org/IATA/2015/00/2018.1/AirShoppingRQ'
];

$document = new DOMDocument();
// adding an element with a namespace adds the definition implicitly
$document->appendChild(
  $envelope = $document->createElementNS($xmlns['soap'], 'soapenv:Envelope')
);
// or add the definition explicitly as attributes
$envelope->setAttributeNS($xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:sec', $xmlns['security']);
$envelope->setAttributeNS($xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:link', $xmlns['link']);
$envelope->setAttributeNS($xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:ses', $xmlns['session']);
$envelope->setAttributeNS($xmlns['xmlns'], 'xmlns:ns', $xmlns['air']);

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```